# How to implement multiple trees with different orientations in D3.js v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a graph in D3.js v4 by using tree layout. As the first step, I started with the example on https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd.Actually, I should have 6 different trees in the big diagram that I want to generate. Since the roots of this trees need to be close to each other, my idea is to locate them through the center of the screen. And, I want to adjust the orientations of each tree manually so that they don't overlap. To better explain, I have drawn a simple diagram shown below where each triangle is for a tree and the roots of the trees are represented by a circle. [image: Diagram overview]

So, how can I locate the trees with different orientations? I know that horizontal and vertical ones are easy to implement, but I couldn't find an example for the orientations having different angles. Also, I'm open to other suggestions such as using a different layout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on this [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3184089), note that I changed the orientation using transform attribute, also I have to mention that this is d3 v3 not v4:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

.border {
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke: #aaa;
}

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 140, right: 10, bottom: 140, left: 100},
    width = 240 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var orientations = {
  "left-to-right": {
    size: [height, width],
    x: function(d) { return d.y; },
    y: function(d) { return d.x; }
  }
};

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(d3.entries(orientations))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ") rotate(50 50 50)");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "border");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3184089/raw/0e0ad03c06635a2db1712019466b56f2b5440b2e/graph.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.each(function(orientation) {
    var svg = d3.select(this),
        o = orientation.value;

    // Compute the layout.
    var tree = d3.layout.tree().size(o.size),
        nodes = tree.nodes(root),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Create the link lines.
    svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [o.x(d), o.y(d)]; }));

    // Create the node circles.
    svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .attr("cx", o.x)
        .attr("cy", o.y);
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Rotating works in v4 too.